# Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound - The asset "my_logo.jpeg" is not present in the asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, precompile, rails-sprockets

Receiving this error, what am I missing?

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotFound in Static#index:

The asset "my_logo.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.

ActionView::Template::Error (The asset "my_logo.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.):
    1: <%= image_tag "my_logo.jpg" %>
```

1. I make a new Ruby on Rails application `rails new my_app` # Rails 6.0.3.2
2. Allow it to install the gems, web packer, etc..
3. Add `config.assets.compile = false` to `config/environments/development.rb`
4. Add a static controller and index file with this content

   **app/controllers/static_controller.r**b

   ```rb
   class StaticController < ApplicationController
     def index
       render :index, layout: false
     end
   end
   ```

   **app/views/static/index.html.erb**

   ```rb
   <%= image_tag "my_logo.jpg" %>
   ```
5. Add the my_logo.jpeg file to `app/assets/images/`

   ```sh
   wget https://jpeg.org/images/jpeg2000-home.jpg -O app/assets/images/my_logo.jpg
   ```
6. Precompile the assets: `bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
7. Run rails server as: `bundle exec rails server`

I can see the file is in `public/assets/` as this name: `my_logo-484af9fb82bc8a0279ef38b527402b5697475bd8f827251f46fbb182be6c07a1.jpg`

It will show the image just fine if I set this to true: `config.assets.compile = true`

Also the manifest file content from `public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-a7f9f10978778e828273bf0c790645f6.json`

```
{
  "files": {
    "manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js": {
      "logical_path": "manifest.js",
      "mtime": "2020-06-28T03:59:01+00:00",
      "size": 2,
      "digest": "75a11da44c802486bc6f65640aa48a730f0f684c5c07a42ba3cd1735eb3fb070",
      "integrity": "sha256-daEdpEyAJIa8b2VkCqSKcw8PaExcB6Qro80XNes/sHA="
    },
    "application-b324c44f04a0d0da658824105489a2676d49df561c3d06723770321fd441977c.css": {
      "logical_path": "application.css",
      "mtime": "2020-06-28T03:59:01+00:00",
      "size": 675,
      "digest": "4998ce12ecefa6ba42de36e4beac458527529608f8cf0fe6c97acd87850045e4",
      "integrity": "sha256-SZjOEuzvprpC3jbkvqxFhSdSlgj4zw/myXrNh4UAReQ="
    },
    "my_logo-484af9fb82bc8a0279ef38b527402b5697475bd8f827251f46fbb182be6c07a1.jpg": {
      "logical_path": "my_logo.jpg",
      "mtime": "2020-06-28T03:59:01+00:00",
      "size": 20974,
      "digest": "acda9fe5166e93aef6ef9572c07e9a6bf3f4879180765b3d95d9a631b852191c",
      "integrity": "sha256-rNqf5RZuk67275VywH6aa/P0h5GAdls9ldmmMbhSGRw="
    }
  },
  "assets": {
    "manifest.js": "manifest-b4bf6e57a53c2bdb55b8998cc94cd00883793c1c37c5e5aea3ef6749b4f6d92b.js",
    "application.css": "application-b324c44f04a0d0da658824105489a2676d49df561c3d06723770321fd441977c.css",
    "my_logo.jpg": "my_logo-484af9fb82bc8a0279ef38b527402b5697475bd8f827251f46fbb182be6c07a1.jpg"
  }
}
```

Also I turned on `config.assets.unknown_asset_fallback = true` to see what the path is, it comes out to being: `http://localhost:3000/images/my_logo.jpg` and when it's false (when it works), I get this path: `http://localhost:3000/assets/my_logo-484af9fb82bc8a0279ef38b527402b5697475bd8f827251f46fbb182be6c07a1.jpg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file in `public/assets` ends in `.jpg`. You're using `.jpeg` in your `image_tag`.

You need to rename your source image to end in `.jpg`, and update your `image_tag` invocation:

```
<%= image_tag('my_logo.jpg') %>
```

Comment: I had that thought also, however it does not change the issue, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have the environment variable: `RAILS_ENV=production` for the server and precompile processes to work.

I found the only reason I needed to run it with `RAILS_ENV=production` because the file: `config/environments/development.rb` had this set to true: `config.assets.debug = true`

If you set this to false: `config.assets.debug = false` - then you can use precompiled assets in development also.

I should have read the comment right above it in the source code:

> Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
>
> This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
>
> number of complex assets.

Also, [@meagar's answer was correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62617596/406959) - don't use `jpeg` extension when everything gets converted to `jpg`. But I wasn't able to see that without also having the answer above.